# BigDecimal Calculation Error at Jython

Tags: jython, bigdecimal

I try to run

```
BigDecimal LOADPROCESSID = BigDecimal(461).Add(new BigDecimal(1))
```

at Jython.

However, I got error message

> ```
> BigDecimal LOADPROCESSID = BigDecimal(461).Add(new BigDecimal(1)) 
>           ^ SyntaxError: mismatched input 'LOADPROCESSID' expecting NEWLINE
> ```

I searched internet and find this code. However, I am not quite familiar with Jython. So I am not sure whether the code is correct for Jython. If not, how can I write this logic in Jython. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Jython you don't have to user 'new' to instanciate an object, neither you
have to declare the type, so simply do

```
import java.math.BigDecimal as bd
LOADPROCESSID = bd(461).add(bd(1))
```

When you will be more confortable whith Jython, you will be able to overload
the 'add' operator.

Regards